# Why is Zero Flag not set when register value is 0?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to use conditional jump instructions.

```
Label:
    mov eax, 0xffffffff
    not eax
    jz Label ; jump only if zero
```

However, jz does not jump to Label. This is because the $eflags shows that ZF is not set. What I do not understand is why ZF is not set when EAX is 0x00000000?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look up the NOT instruction in any x86 programming manual (for example [this PDF from Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf) - it will tell you that flags are not set. So the simple answer is that it doesn't set ZF because it's not supposed to.

If you meant to ask the deeper question of why they designed it that way, sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Not all assembly instructions have an effect on the flags.`not`  does not affect any flag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of not, try using xor eax,0ffffffffh .